# Save Jupyter Notebook with Plotly Express widgets displaying

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-express

I have a Jupyter notebook (python) where I used plotly express to plot in the notebook for analysis purposes.
I want to share this notebook with non-coders, and have the interactive visuals be available still - but it does not seem to work.

I tried following [recommendations made here](https://community.plot.ly/t/export-figurewidgets-from-jupyter-notebook-to-html/15556/2) but even after saving widgets state and using `nbconvert`, when I open the new HTML file, the visuals are not available.

A sample line of plotting can be seen below:

```py
import plotly_express as px
fig = px.scatter(
    df, 
    x='size', 
    y='size_y', 
    color='clients',
    hover_data=['id'], 
    marginal_y="histogram", 
    marginal_x="histogram"
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Can you share a link to your notebook? Are you using `FigureWidget`? If you're not, then just `figure.show()` to display the chart and export to HTML, works without issue for me.

Comment: I cannot share the notebook fully, but added a the line of code where I plot. I used `figure.show()` but it gave the same results, of not displaying the figures when exported to html

Comment: which version of Jupyter and Nbconvert are you using? what's the nbconvert command you're running? this works for me...

Comment: nbconvert 5.4.1 and jupyter 1.0.0 (with Anaconda 2019.03)

Comment: I've also received this warning when trying to convert:
`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\filters\datatypefilter.py:41: UserWarning: Your element with mimetype(s) dict_keys(['application/vnd.plotly.v1+json']) is not able to be represented.
  mimetypes=output.keys())`

Comment: For those looking to do this with notebooks you can publicly share, you can use the intact notebook hosted on Github and then provide others with the URL pointing [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) at the notebook at Github. nbviewer will render the widget. Example at Github not rendering Plotly: https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/Plotly3d-scatter-plots.ipynb. Example of same notebook with nbviewer pointing at Github-posted notebook with Plotly actice still: https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/Plotly3d-scatter-plots.ipynb .

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After running `plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()` in a cell,
you can export the notebook with full interactivity via the file menu:
`File --> Export Notebook as... --> Export Notebook to HTML`.

Comment: This worked for me in Visual Studio Code interactive mode, which builds on the jupyter notebook.

Comment: This works for me using `plotly_express` library as well.

Answer (score 5):

I was having similar issues but with JupyterLab. Followed the instructions here: https://plot.ly/python/renderers/ .

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.keys()
```

I had to add the following snippet to my script:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'jupyterlab'
```

Exporting as HTML after that worked for me. You can read "Overriding the default renderer".

I suppose you would need

```
pio.renderers.default = 'notebook'
```

Comment: Tried doing that, but am still getting an error when creating the html version: `UserWarning: Your element with mimetype(s) dict_keys(['application/vnd.plotly.v1+json']) is not able to be represented.` which I'm assuming has to do with the fact I can't see the figures?

Comment: I think the renderers would be available in newer versions of plotly. The 4.0 update has some info on this: https://community.plot.ly/t/introducing-plotly-py-4-0-0/25639

Comment: This answer produces charts in the HTML output, but the charts are static. For example, tooltips and the interaction menu do not appear.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the default renderers from plotly with:

```py
    import plotly.io as pio
    pio.renderers.default = 'pdf'
```

or when displaying the images with:

```py
    fig.show(renderer="pdf")
```

The 2 choices for you are:

- 'notebook': work well with jupyter notebook;
- 'pdf': perfect when using **nbconvert** to convert to HTML or LATEX

You can also join the 2 with "notebook+pdf" so you have iterative plots when running the notebook and static images when converting with nbconvert.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a problem that resulted in this error message.

```
nbconvert/filters/widgetsdatatypefilter.py:69: UserWarning: Your element with mimetype(s) dict_keys(['application/vnd.plotly.v1+json']) is not able to be represented.
  warn("Your element with mimetype(s) {mimetypes}"
```

Google brought me here, but I could not find a solution from the answers above.

I'm sharing the setup which caused my problem and the solution.

I was running the notebook in VS Code and then on the command line using: jupyter nbconvert

To solve it, I had to start jupyter lab and then run it and save it before running nbconvert.