# Plotly graph not showing up in rendered html

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python

I made a notebook in VSC with some plotly histograms.  They show up in VSC under the cell as expected.  However when I convert to html with `jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input main.ipynb` and then load the html file in my browser, those graphs don't show up.  There is a missing place where they should be.  I can see the div in the inspect window but they're just blank space.  In the console I see

```
file:///C:/localpath/plotly.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

which is deriving from (among others)

```
h.load  @   require.min.js:34
```

The `require.min.js` is from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js`

I tried manually adding `<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.18.0.min.js"></script>` to the html file after the title but before the `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>`.

I can see in my network activity that it downloads that js file but then it still tries to download the local version.  I searched the html file and there's no direct reference to plotly.js so it seems it's some interaction with that require.js

If I manually download `https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.18.0.min.js` and save it to the same directory as the html file and rename it to plotly.js then it works but I don't want to have to do that because then it makes sharing the html file extra cumbersome.

How do I get the html file from my notebook to load the remote plotly.js instead of insisting on it coming from a local file at the same relative path?

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658935/save-jupyter-notebook-with-plotly-express-widgets-displaying) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change my renderer to notebook_connected

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "notebook_connected
```